# TypeScript union types don't work with const assertions ('as const')

Tags: javascript, typescript, union-types

Why this code doesn't work ?

```js
const a = [{ name: 'a', label: 'b' }, { name: 'c', label: 'd' }] as const;
const b = [{ name: 'e', label: 'f' }, { name: 'g', label: 'h' }] as const;
type IArr = typeof a | typeof b;

const fn = (arr: IArr) => arr.filter(el => el.name === 'a');
```

Typescript warn when I try to filter or map this array: 
"has signatures, but none of those signatures are compatible with each other"

```
(arr: IArr) => arr.filter(el => {});
```

But it works fine when i spread this array

```
(arr: IArr) => [...arr].filter(el => {});
```

Comment: spreading and destructuring of `arr` has the effect of turning `IArr` into something like `Array<IArr[number]>`, which is an array of a union instead of a union of arrays.  An array of unions has a single `filter()` method which is callable, while the union of arrays has a union of `filter()` methods (one from each array type), all of which are overloaded, so it can't be called, as mentioned in the answer to the question this duplicates.  Good luck!